# Trace identity for $SU(N)$ matrix integral

Tags: group-theory, integration, mathematics, matrix-model

I would like to know if there's a nice way to compute the following:

$$ \int_{SU(N)} \underbrace{ dU}_{\text{Haar Measure}} \mathrm{tr} \left(U^n \right)~?$$

The following is necessary:
$U \in SU(N)$

$dU$ is the haar measure (left invariant measure).

The integration is carried over the whole group manifold.

What I tried:

If $U \in SU(N)$ it can be written as $U = \exp \left(i \vec{\alpha} \cdot \vec{T} \right)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{N^2 -1 }$ and $\vec{T}$ being the generators of SU(N).  THis implies that
$$\mathrm{tr} (U^n) = \mathrm{tr} (\exp(i n \vec{\alpha} \cdot \vec{T}))$$

For every integration range with some $\alpha$, there is an equivalent value $-\alpha$, so i'm convinced the answer has to be real.  However I'm not sure where to proceed from there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132688/discussion-on-question-by-physicsdude-trace-identity-for-sun-matrix-integral).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is not always zero. See my two answers to

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255492/how-to-constructively-combinatorially-prove-schur-weyl-duality?noredirect=1&lq=1

for a formula for such integrals, and my answer to

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330964/nonnegativity-of-an-integral-over-the-unitary-group?noredirect=1&lq=1

for a hopefully instructive practice example.

A general remark is that if $N$ does not divide $n$, then the integral is zero. For $n=kN$, then the result is
$$
\frac{0!1!\cdots (N-1)!}{k!(k+1)!\cdots (k+N-1)!}
\ ({\rm det}(\partial U))^k\ {\rm tr}(U^{kN})\ .
$$
Here $\partial U$ is the matrix given by the differential operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial U_{ij}}$ instead of the matrix elements $U_{ij}$ themselves.

For $k=1$, it is easy to do the computation and find the value $(-1)^{N-1}$.

In general what one can do, is express the power sum in the Schur basis. This involves the characters of the symetric group. Then the only contributions should come for rectangular partitions with $N$ rows and $k$ columns. I would have to spend some time to check details but, I think the result is basically a character value where one partition is with one part $kN$ and the other is $N^k$, i.e., $N$ parts equal to $k$.

---

**Update:**

After looking up the literature a bit here is the result.
Denote by $I(N,k)$ the integral with $n=kN$. The other cases vanish.
One can turn this into an integral over $U(N)$ by writing
$$
I(N,k)=\int_{U(N)}dU\ \overline{({\rm det}\ U)^k}\ {\rm tr}(U^{kN})\ .
$$
When the partitions involved have at most $N$ parts, this group integral inner product is the same as the Hall inner product of symmetric functions of the eigenvalues of $U$.
So
$$
I(N,k)=\langle s_{\lambda},p_{\mu}\rangle=\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}\ .
$$
Here $s_{\lambda}$ is the Schur function for the rectangular partition $\lambda=(k,k,\ldots,k)$, with $n$ parts of size $k$. The $p_{\mu}$ is the power sum corresponding to the partition $\mu=(kN)$, i.e., with a single part of size $kN$. A particular case of the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule says that the symmetric group character value $\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}$ is zero unless $\lambda$ is a hook, in which case one has
$$
\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}=(-1)^{kN-\lambda_1}\ .
$$
But our $\lambda$ is a hook only if $N=1$ or $k=1$. For $k=1$ one recovers my previous formula $(-1)^{N-1}$.

Reference for the stated facts about symmetric functions:

https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/murnaghanNakayama.htm#murnaghanNakayamaRule

Comment: Sorry can you clarify how partitions enter here?  The OP explicitly states that $U^n$ is NOT $n$ tensor products of $U$, so basically $U^n$ still sits in the defining representations.  I can see how partitions would come in if $U^n$ was $U^2:= U\otimes U$ etc... then one can use Weingarten-type calculus...

Comment: $tr\ U^n=x_1^n+\cdots+x_N^n=:p_n(x)$ where the $x$'s are the eigenvalues of $U$. More generally for an integer partition $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots)$ with $\mu_1\ge\mu_2\ge\cdots$, the expression $p_{\mu}$ denotes the product of power sums $p_{\mu_1}(x)p_{\mu_2}(x)\cdots$. So $tr\ U^n=p_{\mu}$ where $\mu$ is the partition $(n,0,0,\ldots)$ or the Ferrers/Young diagram with just one row of $n$ boxes.

Comment: Likewise $s_{\lambda}$ is the sum over semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ of monomials $x_1$ at the power the number $1$ appears in the tableau, times $x_2$ at the power the number $2$ appears in the tableau, etc. The allowed numbers to fill the tableau are $1,2,\ldots,N$. So for $\lambda=(k,k,\ldots)$ with $N$ rows, each column being strictly increasing must be filled by $1,2,\ldots,N$ from top to bottom, exactly. So $s_{\lambda}=(x_1\cdots x_N)^k=(det\ U)^k$.

Comment: Yes I see it now… nicely done.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Thank you. As I said, to lean more about these group integrals, you can study my previous answers that I provided links to.

Comment: yes I will.  I understand your (very clear) answer and its logic but I must admit I’m still short of intuition as to why it is so.  I was inching towards your argument, but I need to internalize why $U^n$ is *really* not just another unitary.

Comment: Of course $U^n$ is a unitary matrix. The issue is the statistical distribution of $U^n$, namely, it is not the same as that of the original $U$. For a simpler example of this phenomenon consider a uniformly distributed number or real random variable $X$ in the interval $[0,1]$. Then $X^2$ is also a random number in $[0,1]$ but it is not unformly distributed like the original $X$ was.

Comment: Yes I “know” this and your example of [0,1] is an excellent illustration.  I will need to construct some examples by myself.   Of course now that I’m convinced I was thinking about this wrong it’s a matter of “undoing” my initial incorrect intuition.  I would never have thought of decomposing in Schur functions for different partitions,  but it’s so clearly right and natural…